# Can I get a question from a former (deleted) account reattached back to my current account

Tags: support, deleted-users

[That question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578197/eclipse-tabs-repositionning) was the only relevant question I had in my previous account, I'd like to reattach it in my current account

Both accounts are associated with the same email, so it proves it was the same owner

Comment: Devils' advocate here -- Does it really matter to have that question reassociated? The 162 rep you would get back does not look like the reason, is there another rationale behind your request?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - The 162 rep would get them over 500, which would give them access to review queues.

Comment: Not sure how you define relevant but I would say there are more candidates to be reattached: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/340414

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I had to search for this question again this morning, still useful now, so that's just because it's a 'good' question

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Looks like 322 rep from here. But that's just me.

Comment: Why did you delete your account in the first place?

Comment: @R.. Because I wasn't really proud of 99% of its questions/answers

Comment: @crl Does this mean your reputation was affected negatively by the questions/answers your were not proud of?

Comment: @idmean No, I had more than 1k, but the content of those Q/A was not something I wanted to show in my resume for example

Comment: This is quite unusual. Usually you would merge the whole accounts with all questions/answers. I don't believe SE devs have implemented a feature to merge just selected questions.

Comment: @Zanon - If the merge feature actually works against deleted accounts then this could be done as a merge + disassociate.

Comment: Just make it a favorite so you don't lose sight of it.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This sounds like an enormous nightmare.  Either

- Someone does this for you as a one-off. This seems wildly unfair to everyone else and a lot of work for someone to satisfy your personal whims.

OR

- An army of people are enlisted to do this full-time for every punter with crummy questions to purge and a fantasy public image to sculpt.  If it's ok for you, it should be ok for everyone.  This is plainly untenable.

OR

- StackExchange builds this into a feature so that everyone can do it.

The latter makes me cringe.  Half the benefit of the account structure is that you learn to improve, think, and behave.  One major source of incentive to post good questions and good answers is that they link to your account and follow you.

If suddenly people were free to post whatever crap they wanted, safe in the knowledge that they could just zap it away into a faceless `user17269126` post whenever they wanted, well... it's tugging at an untidy thread at the edge of the tapestry.  The urge to pull it out can quickly start to unravel the entire thing.

You wanted a clean slate, you got a clean slate.  That seems perfectly fair to me.